# What is the physical reasons for variations in the tangential and normal components in Dielectric to Dielectric Boundary conditions?

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions, dielectric

According to Dielectric to Dielectric Boundary conditions, the tangential components of the
electric field E remain continuous at the boundary of two dielectrics while the tangential
component of electric flux density D is discontinuous. Furthermore, the normal components
of the electric flux density D remain continuous at the boundary of two dielectrics while the
normal component of electric field E is discontinuous. How can we explain this phenomenon physically?

Comment: This is very standard physics that is present in every electromagnetism textbook of the appropriate level.

Answer (score 2):

In Maxwell Equations for the electric field, we have that:
$$ \nabla \times E = - \partial B / \partial t $$
$$ \nabla \cdot E = \rho /\epsilon_0 $$
and you can define the electric flux density as:
$$ D = \epsilon E $$
with $\epsilon$ dielectric constant of that medium (for a more detailed and physical definition, take a look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field)) . 
You can then demonstrate, as done [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields) the condition for each field. 
You have then that if you demonstrated for instance the conservation of the tangential component of E:
$$ E_{t1}  = E_{t2} \rightarrow D_{t1} ε_1 = D_{t2} ε_2 \rightarrow D_{t1} \neq D_{t2} $$
since at an interface $ε_1 \neq ε_2$.
The same can be done for the normal component of D.

Answer (score 1):

The discontinuity in the normal component comes from Gauss's law. If there is a surface charge density, then the normal component of E will need to be discontinuous so that its divergence is properly a delta function on that surface. The divergence of D looks at only the free charge, and a dielectric has none. So its normal component must be continuous.

The condition on the tangential component of E comes from Faraday's law. Since this is an electrostatic problem, the curl of E is 0 everywhere, and so the tangential component of E must be continuous. Meanwhile, the curl of the D field is simply the curl of the polarization field of the dielectric. In a nonlinear medium, this need not be zero, and so the D field might not have a continuous tangential component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very classic question and yet not so simple !

In fact, it depends on what you accept as distributions on the surface. It is not often considered but it can be very useful to consider a double layer of charges. The layer consist of dipoles perpendicular to (S) and of density $\tau $ (in C/m).

In this case the tangential component of the electric field is not continuous and the condition of passage is ${{\overrightarrow{E}}_{\tan }}({{P}_{2}})-{{\overrightarrow{E}}_{\tan }}({{P}_{1}})=-\frac{1}{{{\varepsilon }_{0}}}\overrightarrow{{{\nabla }_{S}}}\tau $

Ref : Electromagnetic Fields, Van Bladel, p 93.